# cognos analytics and cognos insight

Tags: cognos

all,

I just try the latest cognos analytics 11 Trial version. It seems to connect to cloud directly, but when I try to connect to MySql database in remote linux (I go to Manage->Data servers->New, then fill in the server, port...) from windows 8.1. It always raise the followed errors:
XQE-JDB-0004 A problem occurred finding the driver class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver".
It seems JDBC driver has not been installed or configured in the server

My Questions are:

1. For latest cognos analytics 11 trial version in cloud, where to configure the server or install JDBC driver? Or we need to install cognos express sever firstly?
2. For cognos analytics 11, besides cloud version, could we download the usual desktop version? when I click the access trial, it seems to directly connect to the cloud version. I could not find where to download the desktop version of cognos analytics
3. For another cognos software--cognos insight, trial version could only import CSV file, and does NOT support  MySql database. Is it right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. JDBC drivers need to be added to the `<Cognos root>/drivers` folder (as of Cognos 11), so there would be no way for you to add the necessary driver to their cloud installation.  I am assuming they have only chosen to support a subset of data sources for the cloud trial, but I am not aware of a list of which ones they are allowing/supporting.
2. I have not heard of an on-premises Cognos Analytics trial, at least one that you are able to get publicly.  It is certainly possible that IBM's sales folks would make that happen if it was a potential sales driver for them, but that is conjecture only.
3. Cognos Insight is capable of several things, one of which is being able to analyze CSV data brought in locally.  More specifically, Cognos Insight supports getting data from the following:

   - CSV files
   - Microsoft Excel spreadsheets
   - ODBC data sources
   - IBM Cognos BI Reports
   - IBM Cognos TM1 Cube Views
   - IBM Cognos TM1 Dimension Subsets

Reference: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/infrastructure/cognos_specific/page627.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with an **Oracle** database hence I'm not sure if it helps for MySql, but you could try to perform the following steps:

1. Install the database Drivers (32 & 64 Bit) on the Cognos Server.
2. Open the folder **cognos_install/v5dataserver/** and rename the file *databaseDriverLocations.properties.sample* to *databaseDriverLocations.properties*.
3. Open this file using a text editor and update the **databaseJNIPATH** to point to your database drivers.

In my case I configured the following value:
*databaseJNIPath=C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_64\bin;C:\Oracle\product\12.1.0\client_32\bin;*

See here as well: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21574953